# Oracle: Product Stock vs Quantity Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Hopefully this is the last of many questions about triggers! Still working with the same database where the Order_line entity is a link entity between Order and Products. With this trigger I just want to check if the current order quantity is greater than the stock in Products. At the moment I would be doing this by using two variables, Ordered(quantity) and Total(Stock) and comparing them, but this isn't working.
If the quantity is greater than the stock the record being inserted must be deleted and an error is raised.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Checks_Order
BEFORE INSERT ON order_line
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
ordered int; 
total INT; 

BEGIN
SELECT ol.quantity INTO ordered FROM order_line ol WHERE 
ol.product_no = :new.product_no; 

if(ordered>0) then
SELECT p.stock INTO total FROM
products p WHERE p.product_no = :new.product_no; 
  IF (ordered < total) then 
DELETE FROM order_line ol where ol.order_no = :new.order_no; 
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103, 'Not enough stock!');
END IF;
 END IF;

END;
. 
run
```

Help, please?

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what do you mean? Does it still insert the row? Does it not throw the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger will not work because you cannot select or even delete from the table that the trigger belongs to.

But you don't need to actually, the value that is ordered can be obtained through :new.quantity.

And if you raise an error, the INSERT will not happen, no need to `DELETE` the row.

So - assuming I understood your intention correctly - the following should do what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Checks_Order
BEFORE INSERT ON order_line
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  total INT; 
BEGIN
  if (:new.quantity > 0) then
    SELECT p.stock 
       INTO total 
    FROM products p 
    WHERE p.product_no = :new.product_no; 

    IF (:new.quantity > total) then 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103, 'Not enough stock!');
    END IF;
  END IF;

END;
/
```

Btw: I guess you want `:new.quantity > total` not **< total**

Comment: Great, thanks very much. Sorry about the clumsiness of it all, was a in a bit of a rush. I've added a line to remove the appropriate amount from the product's stock too now, thanks again.